# React Naitve Crashing on Failure delivering result ResultInfo (Image Picker, Document Picker)

Tags: reactjs, image, native, document, picker

> E BufferQueueDebug: com.apppackage/com.apppackage.MainActivity$_6796#0 id info cannot be read from 'com.apppackage/com.apppackage.MainActivity$_6796#0'
> 01-02 21:03:41.985  1269  3478 E WindowManager: win=Window{43d3d6e u0 com.apppackage/com.apppackage.MainActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5866 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5847 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5911 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6553 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:254 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:130
> 01-02 21:03:46.644  6796  6796 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=41, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:1000000608 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.apppackage/com.apppackage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback.invoke(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference

App is crashing once the back button is pressing. App is expected to resume once the document/image is selected.

```
"react-native": "~0.62.2",
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it was due to a package called `react-native-upi-payment`
onResult callback is calling during picking the image as a result null pointer exception occurred. the issue is still open in [Github](https://github.com/nitish24p/react-native-upi/issues/31). For resolving this  Either you can do a postscript after npm install or directly change  callback `onActivityResult` in `UpiPaymentModule.Java`

[image]

Comment: solved!!. Thank you. Now working fine..